# Can't load Icon in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a beginner in React native 
I used http://nativebase.io/ for my example
but I have a problem with the Icon.
My App does not show the Icon

- My App:

[image]

- Code:

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
 import { Container,Header,Content,Title,Badge,Tabs,Button,Icon} from 'native-base';
import Com_DetailCook from './component/Com_DetailCook';

 class CookApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' />
                    </Button>

                    <Title>CookApp</Title>

                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='ios-menu' />
                    </Button>
                </Header>

                <Content>
                      <Com_DetailCook/>
                </Content>

            </Container>
         );
     }
 }


AppRegistry.registerComponent('CookApp', () => CookApp);
```

- And config Icon for Guide (github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: All icons don't work ?

Comment: Yes. All Icons don't work. You can watch My config at image "My App: enter image description here"

Comment: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/76

Comment: Look like the same issues

Comment: try running `rnpm link`

Comment: Thanks All. I resolved it
Used:
 **rnpm link react-native-vector-icons**

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've read on the issues of the react-native-vector-icons library. You need to install it manually sometimes the linking it's not working.

Take a look at this issues

- https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/76
- https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/233

For a guide to install it look at the docs here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-manually

Hope that help ;)

Comment: Thanks All. I resolved it
Used:
 **rnpm link react-native-vector-icons**

Comment: Perfect happy to hear that ;) Good job